# mysql update or insert multiple records if not already exists in a table

Tags: php, mysql

there is a table named "inventory_item" in a mysql database. "id", "product_id" and "quantity" are columns of the table. "id" is the primary key and auto generate when a record is inserted.

when the user submit the form which is to insert multiple records to the table all the data of product_ids and their quantities can be collected in foreach loop.

so i need to insert multiple records at the same time and should only update quantity if "product_id" is already exist in the table without inserting as a new record.

here is my code block..

```
foreach ($dataArray as $value) { 
    $pcid = $value["pcid"];
    $quantity = $value["quantity"];
    $sql = "
        UPDATE table.inventory_item
        SET quantity='$quantity'
        WHERE product_category_id='$pcid'
        IF ROW_COUNT()=0
        INSERT INTO table.inventory_item
            (product_category_id, quantity)
        VALUES ('$pcid', '$quantity')
    ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    var_dump($result);
}
```

Comment: you just want to update qty with previous qty for existing item or add with old qty?

Comment: You'll need to issue multiple statements so make sure do that inside a transaction (`begin` and `commit`) in order to maintain data integrity.

Answer (score 3):

**INSERT INTO ..... ON DUPLICATE KEY ....** ist your friend. with this combination you can insert new records or update exiting records. for this it is necessary to have a unique key on a field that define your row like: **product_category_id** in your sample

*a table with unique Key**

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_id` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Sample**

```
mysql> select * from `table`;
Empty set (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT into `table` (product_id,quantity) Values ('p1',9),('p2',13) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity=VALUES(quantity);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0,01 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from `table`;
+----+------------+----------+
| id | product_id | quantity |
+----+------------+----------+
|  9 | p1         |        9 |
| 10 | p2         |       13 |
+----+------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT into `table` (product_id,quantity) Values ('p3',9),('p2',15) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity=VALUES(quantity);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0,00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from `table`;
+----+------------+----------+
| id | product_id | quantity |
+----+------------+----------+
|  9 | p1         |        9 |
| 10 | p2         |       15 |
| 11 | p3         |        9 |
+----+------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use any one of the following as per your requirement.

***REPLACE INTO***

if the record is not already available on table it will simply insert else if it is already available on it will delete the record and insert new record.

```
REPLACE INTO table.inventory_item (product_category_id, quantity) SELECT '$quantity' ,'$pcid';
```

**ON DUPLICATE  KEY UPDATE**

if the record is not already available on table it will simply insert else if it is already available on run the respective update command.

```
INSERT INTO table.inventory_item (product_category_id, quantity) VALUES ('$pcid', '$quantity')" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE table.inventory_item SET quantity='$quantity' WHERE product_category_id='$pcid';
```

Hope this helps.